# Array of objects in Python for instant access

Tags: python, arrays

I figured it would be simple to created an array of class objects in Python, but [the built-in array type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) only supports basic data types. Is [NumPy's ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arrays-ndarray) the next best thing?

I want O(1) access time by index.

Comment: Use a list? Lists have constant-time indexing.

Comment: @Rawing do they? Didn't know that. Is that given by the language definition, or a specific implementation?

Comment: @Rawing How do you know that? Link to official documentation, please.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't think it's part of the language specification, but it's true for CPython: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @Rawing yeah, in CPython, `struct PyListObject` contains a `PyObject**` (i.e. a pointer to an array of `pyObject`s), which implies constant (read) access.